# Compiling Qt projects on Ubuntu fails every time

Tags: qt, compiler-construction, qt-creator, bitcoin

### History

I've started mining on www.multiport.us and as such I am mining many different coins. Scrypt coins and sha-256.

I'd rather not have all my coins on Cryptsy or Vircuex, so I'm trying to get the Qt GUIs for each of the coins install compiled so I can have wallets on my PC.

### Problem

I've been trying for several days now to get this stuff working and I just can't. I've tried with several different coins - Feathercoin, Novacoin, Namecoin, Worldcoin, Freicoin, Zetacoin, etc.

I have tried terminal, and Qt Creator, but I get different errors on each wallet, almost always missing program errors. I get missing bitcoin.cpp, missing QApplication, etc, etc. They just refuse to compile.

### Fixes tried

In Qt Creator I have tried adding QT += Widgets, tried a couple of other things too.

In terminal I was originally using 'qmake', then 'make'. But that's been giving me various errors. Missing locale/****, or missing `<QApplication>`

I have been getting all my source files from the official SourceForge pages, and trying the latest releases and the "master" file list.

### System

Ubuntu 13.10
qmake QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.0.2 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
QTCreator version 2.7.1

Following the readme's and instructional files i have also installed the following dependancies

```
qt4-qmake 
libqt4-dev 
build-essential 
libboost-dev 
libboost-system-dev 
libboost-filesystem-dev 
libboost-program-options-dev 
libboost-thread-dev \
libssl-dev 
libdb++-dev 
libminiupnpc-dev 
libgmp3-dev 
libmpfr-dev
```

I really don't know what the problem is. I'm guessing it has something to do with being on 13.10, either that or there is something major I'm just not seeing. But all the source files are the same, they are built so all you need to do is qmake and make, to compile on your own system and then run. But I'm just having no luck at all.

---

QT Creator is version 2.7.1 from the repository.

Here is the .pro file I'm using.

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = bitcoin-qt
macx:TARGET = "Bitcoin-Qt"
VERSION = 0.8.3
INCLUDEPATH += src src/json src/qt
QT += network
DEFINES += QT_GUI BOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB BOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE
CONFIG += no_include_pwd
CONFIG += thread

# for boost 1.37, add -mt to the boost libraries
# use: qmake BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX=-mt
# for boost thread win32 with _win32 sufix
# use: BOOST_THREAD_LIB_SUFFIX=_win32-...
# or when linking against a specific BerkelyDB version: BDB_LIB_SUFFIX=-4.8

# Dependency library locations can be customized with:
#    BOOST_INCLUDE_PATH, BOOST_LIB_PATH, BDB_INCLUDE_PATH,
#    BDB_LIB_PATH, OPENSSL_INCLUDE_PATH and OPENSSL_LIB_PATH respectively

OBJECTS_DIR = build
MOC_DIR = build
UI_DIR = build

# use: qmake "RELEASE=1"
contains(RELEASE, 1) {
    # Mac: compile for maximum compatibility (10.5, 32-bit)
    macx:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk
    macx:QMAKE_CFLAGS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk
    macx:QMAKE_OBJECTIVE_CFLAGS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk

    !win32:!macx {
        # Linux: static link and extra security (see: https://wiki.debian.org/Hardening)
        LIBS += -Wl,-Bstatic -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now
    }
}

!win32 {
    # for extra security against potential buffer overflows: enable GCCs Stack Smashing Protection
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS *= -fstack-protector-all
    QMAKE_LFLAGS *= -fstack-protector-all
    # Exclude on Windows cross compile with MinGW 4.2.x, as it will result in a non-working executable!
    # This can be enabled for Windows, when we switch to MinGW >= 4.4.x.
}
# for extra security (see: https://wiki.debian.org/Hardening): this flag is GCC compiler-specific
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS *= -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
# for extra security on Windows: enable ASLR and DEP via GCC linker flags
win32:QMAKE_LFLAGS *= -Wl,--dynamicbase -Wl,--nxcompat
# on Windows: enable GCC large address aware linker flag
win32:QMAKE_LFLAGS *= -Wl,--large-address-aware

# use: qmake "USE_QRCODE=1"
# libqrencode (http://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/index.en.html) must be installed for support
contains(USE_QRCODE, 1) {
    message(Building with QRCode support)
    DEFINES += USE_QRCODE
    LIBS += -lqrencode
}

# use: qmake "USE_UPNP=1" ( enabled by default; default)
#  or: qmake "USE_UPNP=0" (disabled by default)
#  or: qmake "USE_UPNP=-" (not supported)
# miniupnpc (http://miniupnp.free.fr/files/) must be installed for support
contains(USE_UPNP, -) {
    message(Building without UPNP support)
} else {
    message(Building with UPNP support)
    count(USE_UPNP, 0) {
        USE_UPNP=1
    }
    DEFINES += USE_UPNP=$$USE_UPNP STATICLIB
    INCLUDEPATH += $$MINIUPNPC_INCLUDE_PATH
    LIBS += $$join(MINIUPNPC_LIB_PATH,,-L,) -lminiupnpc
    win32:LIBS += -liphlpapi
}

# use: qmake "USE_DBUS=1"
contains(USE_DBUS, 1) {
    message(Building with DBUS (Freedesktop notifications) support)
    DEFINES += USE_DBUS
    QT += dbus
}

# use: qmake "USE_IPV6=1" ( enabled by default; default)
#  or: qmake "USE_IPV6=0" (disabled by default)
#  or: qmake "USE_IPV6=-" (not supported)
contains(USE_IPV6, -) {
    message(Building without IPv6 support)
} else {
    count(USE_IPV6, 0) {
        USE_IPV6=1
    }
    DEFINES += USE_IPV6=$$USE_IPV6
}

contains(BITCOIN_NEED_QT_PLUGINS, 1) {
    DEFINES += BITCOIN_NEED_QT_PLUGINS
    QTPLUGIN += qcncodecs qjpcodecs qtwcodecs qkrcodecs qtaccessiblewidgets
}

INCLUDEPATH += src/leveldb/include src/leveldb/helpers
LIBS += $$PWD/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a $$PWD/src/leveldb/libmemenv.a
!win32 {
    # we use QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE even without RELEASE=1 because we use RELEASE to indicate linking preferences not -O preferences
    genleveldb.commands = cd $$PWD/src/leveldb && CC=$$QMAKE_CC CXX=$$QMAKE_CXX $(MAKE) OPT=\"$$QMAKE_CXXFLAGS $$QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE\" libleveldb.a libmemenv.a
} else {
    # make an educated guess about what the ranlib command is called
    isEmpty(QMAKE_RANLIB) {
        QMAKE_RANLIB = $$replace(QMAKE_STRIP, strip, ranlib)
    }
    LIBS += -lshlwapi
    genleveldb.commands = cd $$PWD/src/leveldb && CC=$$QMAKE_CC CXX=$$QMAKE_CXX TARGET_OS=OS_WINDOWS_CROSSCOMPILE $(MAKE) OPT=\"$$QMAKE_CXXFLAGS $$QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE\" libleveldb.a libmemenv.a && $$QMAKE_RANLIB $$PWD/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a && $$QMAKE_RANLIB $$PWD/src/leveldb/libmemenv.a
}
genleveldb.target = $$PWD/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a
genleveldb.depends = FORCE
PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += genleveldb
# Gross ugly hack that depends on qmake internals, unfortunately there is no other way to do it.
QMAKE_CLEAN += $$PWD/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a; cd $$PWD/src/leveldb ; $(MAKE) clean

# regenerate src/build.h
!win32|contains(USE_BUILD_INFO, 1) {
    genbuild.depends = FORCE
    genbuild.commands = cd $$PWD; /bin/sh share/genbuild.sh $$OUT_PWD/build/build.h
    genbuild.target = $$OUT_PWD/build/build.h
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$OUT_PWD/build/build.h
    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += genbuild
    DEFINES += HAVE_BUILD_INFO
}

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON = -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wall -Wextra -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstack-protector

# Input
DEPENDPATH += src src/json src/qt
HEADERS += src/qt/bitcoingui.h \
    src/qt/transactiontablemodel.h \
    src/qt/addresstablemodel.h \
    src/qt/optionsdialog.h \
    src/qt/sendcoinsdialog.h \
    src/qt/addressbookpage.h \
    src/qt/signverifymessagedialog.h \
    src/qt/aboutdialog.h \
    src/qt/editaddressdialog.h \
    src/qt/bitcoinaddressvalidator.h \
    src/alert.h \
    src/addrman.h \
    src/base58.h \
    src/bignum.h \
    src/checkpoints.h \
    src/compat.h \
    src/sync.h \
    src/util.h \
    src/hash.h \
    src/uint256.h \
    src/serialize.h \
    src/main.h \
    src/net.h \
    src/key.h \
    src/db.h \
    src/walletdb.h \
    src/script.h \
    src/init.h \
    src/bloom.h \
    src/mruset.h \
    src/checkqueue.h \
    src/json/json_spirit_writer_template.h \
    src/json/json_spirit_writer.h \
    src/json/json_spirit_value.h \
    src/json/json_spirit_utils.h \
    src/json/json_spirit_stream_reader.h \
    src/json/json_spirit_reader_template.h \
    src/json/json_spirit_reader.h \
    src/json/json_spirit_error_position.h \
    src/json/json_spirit.h \
    src/qt/clientmodel.h \
    src/qt/guiutil.h \
    src/qt/transactionrecord.h \
    src/qt/guiconstants.h \
    src/qt/optionsmodel.h \
    src/qt/monitoreddatamapper.h \
    src/qt/transactiondesc.h \
    src/qt/transactiondescdialog.h \
    src/qt/bitcoinamountfield.h \
    src/wallet.h \
    src/keystore.h \
    src/qt/transactionfilterproxy.h \
    src/qt/transactionview.h \
    src/qt/walletmodel.h \
    src/qt/walletview.h \
    src/qt/walletstack.h \
    src/qt/walletframe.h \
    src/bitcoinrpc.h \
    src/qt/overviewpage.h \
    src/qt/csvmodelwriter.h \
    src/crypter.h \
    src/qt/sendcoinsentry.h \
    src/qt/qvalidatedlineedit.h \
    src/qt/bitcoinunits.h \
    src/qt/qvaluecombobox.h \
    src/qt/askpassphrasedialog.h \
    src/protocol.h \
    src/qt/notificator.h \
    src/qt/paymentserver.h \
    src/allocators.h \
    src/ui_interface.h \
    src/qt/rpcconsole.h \
    src/version.h \
    src/netbase.h \
    src/clientversion.h \
    src/txdb.h \
    src/leveldb.h \
    src/threadsafety.h \
    src/limitedmap.h \
    src/qt/splashscreen.h

SOURCES += src/qt/bitcoin.cpp \
    src/qt/bitcoingui.cpp \
    src/qt/transactiontablemodel.cpp \
    src/qt/addresstablemodel.cpp \
    src/qt/optionsdialog.cpp \
    src/qt/sendcoinsdialog.cpp \
    src/qt/addressbookpage.cpp \
    src/qt/signverifymessagedialog.cpp \
    src/qt/aboutdialog.cpp \
    src/qt/editaddressdialog.cpp \
    src/qt/bitcoinaddressvalidator.cpp \
    src/alert.cpp \
    src/version.cpp \
    src/sync.cpp \
    src/util.cpp \
    src/hash.cpp \
    src/netbase.cpp \
    src/key.cpp \
    src/script.cpp \
    src/main.cpp \
    src/init.cpp \
    src/net.cpp \
    src/bloom.cpp \
    src/checkpoints.cpp \
    src/addrman.cpp \
    src/db.cpp \
    src/walletdb.cpp \
    src/qt/clientmodel.cpp \
    src/qt/guiutil.cpp \
    src/qt/transactionrecord.cpp \
    src/qt/optionsmodel.cpp \
    src/qt/monitoreddatamapper.cpp \
    src/qt/transactiondesc.cpp \
    src/qt/transactiondescdialog.cpp \
    src/qt/bitcoinstrings.cpp \
    src/qt/bitcoinamountfield.cpp \
    src/wallet.cpp \
    src/keystore.cpp \
    src/qt/transactionfilterproxy.cpp \
    src/qt/transactionview.cpp \
    src/qt/walletmodel.cpp \
    src/qt/walletview.cpp \
    src/qt/walletstack.cpp \
    src/qt/walletframe.cpp \
    src/bitcoinrpc.cpp \
    src/rpcdump.cpp \
    src/rpcnet.cpp \
    src/rpcmining.cpp \
    src/rpcwallet.cpp \
    src/rpcblockchain.cpp \
    src/rpcrawtransaction.cpp \
    src/qt/overviewpage.cpp \
    src/qt/csvmodelwriter.cpp \
    src/crypter.cpp \
    src/qt/sendcoinsentry.cpp \
    src/qt/qvalidatedlineedit.cpp \
    src/qt/bitcoinunits.cpp \
    src/qt/qvaluecombobox.cpp \
    src/qt/askpassphrasedialog.cpp \
    src/protocol.cpp \
    src/qt/notificator.cpp \
    src/qt/paymentserver.cpp \
    src/qt/rpcconsole.cpp \
    src/noui.cpp \
    src/leveldb.cpp \
    src/txdb.cpp \
    src/qt/splashscreen.cpp

RESOURCES += src/qt/bitcoin.qrc

FORMS += src/qt/forms/sendcoinsdialog.ui \
    src/qt/forms/addressbookpage.ui \
    src/qt/forms/signverifymessagedialog.ui \
    src/qt/forms/aboutdialog.ui \
    src/qt/forms/editaddressdialog.ui \
    src/qt/forms/transactiondescdialog.ui \
    src/qt/forms/overviewpage.ui \
    src/qt/forms/sendcoinsentry.ui \
    src/qt/forms/askpassphrasedialog.ui \
    src/qt/forms/rpcconsole.ui \
    src/qt/forms/optionsdialog.ui

contains(USE_QRCODE, 1) {
HEADERS += src/qt/qrcodedialog.h
SOURCES += src/qt/qrcodedialog.cpp
FORMS += src/qt/forms/qrcodedialog.ui
}

contains(BITCOIN_QT_TEST, 1) {
SOURCES += src/qt/test/test_main.cpp \
    src/qt/test/uritests.cpp
HEADERS += src/qt/test/uritests.h
DEPENDPATH += src/qt/test
QT += testlib
TARGET = bitcoin-qt_test
DEFINES += BITCOIN_QT_TEST
  macx: CONFIG -= app_bundle
}

CODECFORTR = UTF-8

# for lrelease/lupdate
# also add new translations to src/qt/bitcoin.qrc under translations/
TRANSLATIONS = $$files(src/qt/locale/bitcoin_*.ts)

isEmpty(QMAKE_LRELEASE) {
    win32:QMAKE_LRELEASE = $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]\\lrelease.exe
    else:QMAKE_LRELEASE = $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]/lrelease
}
isEmpty(QM_DIR):QM_DIR = $$PWD/src/qt/locale
# automatically build translations, so they can be included in resource file
TSQM.name = lrelease ${QMAKE_FILE_IN}
TSQM.input = TRANSLATIONS
TSQM.output = $$QM_DIR/${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.qm
TSQM.commands = $$QMAKE_LRELEASE ${QMAKE_FILE_IN} -qm ${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
TSQM.CONFIG = no_link
QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += TSQM

# "Other files" to show in Qt Creator
OTHER_FILES += README.md \
    doc/*.rst \
    doc/*.txt \
    src/qt/res/bitcoin-qt.rc \
    src/test/*.cpp \
    src/test/*.h \
    src/qt/test/*.cpp \
    src/qt/test/*.h

# platform specific defaults, if not overridden on command line
isEmpty(BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX) {
    macx:BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX = -mt
    win32:BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX = -mgw44-mt-s-1_50
}

isEmpty(BOOST_THREAD_LIB_SUFFIX) {
    BOOST_THREAD_LIB_SUFFIX = $$BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX
}

isEmpty(BDB_LIB_PATH) {
    macx:BDB_LIB_PATH = /opt/local/lib/db48
}

isEmpty(BDB_LIB_SUFFIX) {
    macx:BDB_LIB_SUFFIX = -4.8
}

isEmpty(BDB_INCLUDE_PATH) {
    macx:BDB_INCLUDE_PATH = /opt/local/include/db48
}

isEmpty(BOOST_LIB_PATH) {
    macx:BOOST_LIB_PATH = /opt/local/lib
}

isEmpty(BOOST_INCLUDE_PATH) {
    macx:BOOST_INCLUDE_PATH = /opt/local/include
}

win32:DEFINES += WIN32
win32:RC_FILE = src/qt/res/bitcoin-qt.rc

win32:!contains(MINGW_THREAD_BUGFIX, 0) {
    # At least qmake's win32-g++-cross profile is missing the -lmingwthrd
    # thread-safety flag. GCC has -mthreads to enable this, but it doesn't
    # work with static linking. -lmingwthrd must come BEFORE -lmingw, so
    # it is prepended to QMAKE_LIBS_QT_ENTRY.
    # It can be turned off with MINGW_THREAD_BUGFIX=0, just in case it causes
    # any problems on some untested qmake profile now or in the future.
    DEFINES += _MT
    QMAKE_LIBS_QT_ENTRY = -lmingwthrd $$QMAKE_LIBS_QT_ENTRY
}

!win32:!macx {
    DEFINES += LINUX
    LIBS += -lrt
    # _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 lets 32-bit fopen transparently support large files.
    DEFINES += _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64
}

macx:HEADERS += src/qt/macdockiconhandler.h
macx:OBJECTIVE_SOURCES += src/qt/macdockiconhandler.mm
macx:LIBS += -framework Foundation -framework ApplicationServices -framework AppKit
macx:DEFINES += MAC_OSX MSG_NOSIGNAL=0
macx:ICON = src/qt/res/icons/bitcoin.icns
macx:QMAKE_CFLAGS_THREAD += -pthread
macx:QMAKE_LFLAGS_THREAD += -pthread
macx:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_THREAD += -pthread
macx:QMAKE_INFO_PLIST = share/qt/Info.plist

# Set libraries and includes at end, to use platform-defined defaults if not overridden
INCLUDEPATH += $$BOOST_INCLUDE_PATH $$BDB_INCLUDE_PATH $$OPENSSL_INCLUDE_PATH $$QRENCODE_INCLUDE_PATH
LIBS += $$join(BOOST_LIB_PATH,,-L,) $$join(BDB_LIB_PATH,,-L,) $$join(OPENSSL_LIB_PATH,,-L,) $$join(QRENCODE_LIB_PATH,,-L,)
LIBS += -lssl -lcrypto -ldb_cxx$$BDB_LIB_SUFFIX
# -lgdi32 has to happen after -lcrypto (see  #681)
win32:LIBS += -lws2_32 -lshlwapi -lmswsock -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lgdi32
LIBS += -lboost_system$$BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX -lboost_filesystem$$BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX -lboost_program_options$$BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX -lboost_thread$$BOOST_THREAD_LIB_SUFFIX
win32:LIBS += -lboost_chrono$$BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX
macx:LIBS += -lboost_chrono$$BOOST_LIB_SUFFIX

contains(RELEASE, 1) {
    !win32:!macx {
        # Linux: turn dynamic linking back on for c/c++ runtime libraries
        LIBS += -Wl,-Bdynamic
    }
}

system($$QMAKE_LRELEASE -silent $$TRANSLATIONS)
```

As I have said the instructions that all of the wallets I'm trying to compile come with say the exact same thing.

```
Bitcoin-Qt: Qt4 GUI for Bitcoin
===============================

Build instructions
===================

Debian
-------

First, make sure that the required packages for Qt4 development of your
distribution are installed, these are

::

for Debian and Ubuntu  <= 11.10 :

::

    apt-get install qt4-qmake libqt4-dev build-essential libboost-dev libboost-system-dev \
        libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-thread-dev \
        libssl-dev libdb4.8++-dev

for Ubuntu >= 12.04 (please read the 'Berkely DB version warning' below):

::

    apt-get install qt4-qmake libqt4-dev build-essential libboost-dev libboost-system-dev \
        libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-program-options-dev libboost-thread-dev \
        libssl-dev libdb++-dev libminiupnpc-dev

then execute the following:

::

    qmake
    make

Alternatively, install `Qt Creator`_ and open the `bitcoin-qt.pro` file.

An executable named `bitcoin-qt` will be built.

.. _`Qt Creator`: http://qt-project.org/downloads/

Mac OS X
--------

- Download and install the `Qt Mac OS X SDK`_. It is recommended to also install Apple's Xcode with UNIX tools.

- Download and install either `MacPorts`_ or `HomeBrew`_.

- Execute the following commands in a terminal to get the dependencies using MacPorts:

::

    sudo port selfupdate
    sudo port install boost db48 miniupnpc

- Execute the following commands in a terminal to get the dependencies using HomeBrew:

::

    brew update
    brew install boost miniupnpc openssl berkeley-db4

- If using HomeBrew,  edit `bitcoin-qt.pro` to account for library location differences. There's a diff in `contrib/homebrew/bitcoin-qt-pro.patch` that shows what you need to change, or you can just patch by doing

        patch -p1 < contrib/homebrew/bitcoin.qt.pro.patch

- Open the bitcoin-qt.pro file in Qt Creator and build as normal (cmd-B)

.. _`Qt Mac OS X SDK`: http://qt-project.org/downloads/
.. _`MacPorts`: http://www.macports.org/install.php
.. _`HomeBrew`: http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/


Build configuration options
============================

UPnP port forwarding
---------------------

To use UPnP for port forwarding behind a NAT router (recommended, as more connections overall allow for a faster and more stable bitcoin experience), pass the following argument to qmake:

::

    qmake "USE_UPNP=1"

(in **Qt Creator**, you can find the setting for additional qmake arguments under "Projects" -> "Build Settings" -> "Build Steps", then click "Details" next to **qmake**)

This requires miniupnpc for UPnP port mapping.  It can be downloaded from
http://miniupnp.tuxfamily.org/files/.  UPnP support is not compiled in by default.

Set USE_UPNP to a different value to control this:

+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| USE_UPNP=- | no UPnP support, miniupnpc not required;                                 |
+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| USE_UPNP=0 | (the default) built with UPnP, support turned off by default at runtime; |
+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| USE_UPNP=1 | build with UPnP support turned on by default at runtime.                 |
+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Notification support for recent (k)ubuntu versions
---------------------------------------------------

To see desktop notifications on (k)ubuntu versions starting from 10.04, enable usage of the
FreeDesktop notification interface through DBUS using the following qmake option:

::

    qmake "USE_DBUS=1"

Generation of QR codes
-----------------------

libqrencode may be used to generate QRCode images for payment requests.
It can be downloaded from http://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/index.html.en, or installed via your package manager. Pass the USE_QRCODE
flag to qmake to control this:

+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| USE_QRCODE=0 | (the default) No QRCode support - libarcode not required                 |
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| USE_QRCODE=1 | QRCode support enabled                                                   |
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+


Berkely DB version warning
==========================

A warning for people using the *static binary* version of Bitcoin on a Linux/UNIX-ish system (tl;dr: **Berkely DB databases are not forward compatible**).

The static binary version of Bitcoin is linked against libdb4.8 (see also `this Debian issue`_).

Now the nasty thing is that databases from 5.X are not compatible with 4.X.

If the globally installed development package of Berkely DB installed on your system is 5.X, any source you
build yourself will be linked against that. The first time you run with a 5.X version the database will be upgraded,
and 4.X cannot open the new format. This means that you cannot go back to the old statically linked version without
significant hassle!

.. _`this Debian issue`: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=621425

Ubuntu 11.10 warning
====================

Ubuntu 11.10 has a package called 'qt-at-spi' installed by default.  At the time of writing, having that package
installed causes bitcoin-qt to crash intermittently.  The issue has been reported as `launchpad bug 857790`_, but
isn't yet fixed.

Until the bug is fixed, you can remove the qt-at-spi package to work around the problem, though this will presumably
disable screen reader functionality for Qt apps:

::

    sudo apt-get remove qt-at-spi

.. _`launchpad bug 857790`: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qt-at-spi/+bug/857790
```

But when I try and compile with QT Creator or through terminal I get:

```
home/kun7/CoinMining/zetacoin-0.8.3/src/qt/bitcoin.cpp:5: error: QApplication: No such file or directory
```

I have found that lots of people are adding 'QT += widgets' to their .ro files and it fixes it, but when I do that I get:

```
/home/kun7/CoinMining/zetacoin-0.8.3/src/qt/bitcoin.cpp:122: error: 'setCodecForTr' is not a member of 'QTextCodec'
/home/kun7/CoinMining/zetacoin-0.8.3/src/qt/bitcoin.cpp:123: error: 'setCodecForCStrings' is not a member of 'QTextCodec'
/home/kun7/CoinMining/zetacoin-0.8.3/src/qt/bitcoin.cpp:123: error: 'codecForTr' is not a member of 'QTextCodec'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You said you're using Qt 5.0.2, but you're installing libqt4-dev (which provides Qt 4.8). Which version of Qt does your program require? Also, I recommend compiling from within Qt Creator -- it manages a lot of behind-the-scenes config for you.

Comment: Add the exact error, the .pro file, and how you configured Qt Creator (which Qt version, compiler etc.)

Comment: Im on a fresh install of ubuntu 13.10, The altcoin wallets all require the same version of QT. I went through the install instructions and installed the dependancies through terminal with no errors. I have tried installing through QT Creator and it gives me errors too. Most of the time i get missing program <QApplication> errors. but when I add QT += widgets it then gives me syntax errors.

Comment: Qt += widgets is Qt5. "Bitcoin-Qt: Qt4 GUI for Bitcoin" suggests Bitcoin is Qt4. You cannot mix them. Configure a Qt4 "Kit" in Qt Creator to make sure creator builds bitcoin with qt4. I'd try from the command line first.

Comment: I've tried making from the command line and i still get the same errors. Hw would i go about making a QT4 Kit? Sounds interesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue has been fixed!!!

I was a moron.

I was trying to run

```
qmake
make
```

But my system has qmake version 5 installed and i installed verion 4 as per the dependencies. So instead, to get the program to compile correctly, i need to force the use of version 4...

```
qmake-qt4
make
```

Voiala!!!!!

Comment: I suggest accepting your own answer since it seems to be the right one :) Been scouring the interwebs for an answer for 3 hours now. Ubuntu 13.04 here.